# A script accept a path as parameter and then delete all empty dirs needs some enhancement

Tags: powershell, directory

With help from @Shay Levy I have such a script:

```
param (
[parameter (mandatory=$true,position=0)]
[string]$Path
)
Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -Force | 
Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -and (Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Force | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0} | Remove-Item
```

What it does is: accept a path as parameter - find all dirs recursively - if it is a empty folder (no childitem underneath), it will get removed. It works fine but I want to make it perfect.

Example to explain a special situation: I have a folder as such folder structure: `folder/subfolder1.1/subfolder2.1/subfolder3.1.` Every sub folder is the only child item underneath its parent. I have a dir called "folder", and it contains only one subfolder "subfolder1.1" and no files. "Subfolder1.1" contains only one subfolder "subfolder2.1" and no files. "subfolder2.1" contains "subfolder3.1" and no files. After running this script, what really gets removed is "subfolder3.1" which makes sense.

Here comes something: After "subfolder3.1" being removed its parent folder "subfolder2.1" becoming empty folder and can be removed. But since the script has passed that point, "subfolder2.1" can not be removed until I run the script one more time.

The perfect script will: remove "subfolder3.1" first, then checks its parent folder and find "Oh, its parent subfolder2.1 is empty too now, let's delete it parent folder subfolder2.1". After removing subfolder2.1, then checks its parent and find "Oh, subfolder1.1 is empty now, let's delete it". Eventually, after all sub folders get removed, the top level of this structure "folder" will get removed since it is empty.

I add a "sort -descending" in the script and it seems doesn't do anything for me.

```
param (
[parameter (mandatory=$true,position=0)]
[string]$Path
)
Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -Force | 
Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -and (Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Force | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0} | 
Sort -descending |Remove-Item
```

The logics adding "sort" command is: The above folder structure is piped in this order:

```
folder
folder/subfolder1.1
folder/subfolder1.1/subfolder2.1
folder/subfolder1.1/subfolder2.1/subfolder3.1
```

In above order, after "folder/subfolder1.1/subfolder2.1/subfolder3.1" removed, 2.1 and 1.1 and folder can not be removed since the script has passed the points. So I was putting "sort -descending" in the script hoping this folder structure be piped this in this order:

```
folder/subfolder1.1/subfolder2.1/subfolder3.1
folder/subfolder1.1/subfolder2.1
folder/subfolder1.1
folder
```

My hope is that it remove 3.1 first, then it can remove 2.1 since 2.1 becoming empty after 3.1 getting removed. And so on. This dream is beautiful but it doesn't work.

==================================
Update1:

Apr 25, 2013: @mjolinor Thank you for help. I run it right away and get such an error:

...............

```
+ Foreach {
+        ~
Missing opening '(' after keyword 'foreach'.
```

...............

I fixed it by modifying this line in first foreach loop:

...............

```
Foreach ($dir in $dirs) {
```

...............

Now the above error is gone and moved one step further. When I can run it I can see it is  iterating folders but ended up in another error:

...............

```
Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.
At C:\Documents\ManualScripts\Cleanup-no-file-and-subdir-dir-rev02.ps1:11 char:13
+             $dirs[$_] = (Get-ChildItem $_ -Force | Measure-Object).Count
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArrayIndex
```

...............

Working on it and will share with you.

=============================
Update2:

Apr 25, 2013

The reason for the above error is this line:
...........

```
Foreach ($dir in $dirs) {
```

...........

Change it into:
...........

```
Foreach ($dir in $_) {
```

...........

Error is gone. I can see the list of dirs scrolling down the console. But it  seems like "sort" did not work as I expected since the test folder still show up "ascending" order. The excerpt is as following:

...........

```
H:\archive\folder\Sub1
H:\archive\folder\Sub1\Sub2.1
H:\archive\folder\Sub1\Sub2.1\Sub3.1
```

...........

"folder\Sub1\Sub2.1\Sub3.1" is the test folder structure I created.

===================================
Update 3

Apr 26, 2013.

It works now!

.........................................

```
param (
[parameter (mandatory = $True, position = 0)]
[string]$Path
)
$dirs = @{}

Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -Force |
Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} |
Select -ExpandProperty FullName |
Foreach {
            $dirs[$_] = (Get-ChildItem $_ -Force | Measure-Object).Count
        }
$dirs.keys | Sort Length -Descending # This line is only for displaying output to mornitor sorting is all right
$dirs.keys | Sort Length -Descending  |
Foreach {
         If ($dirs[$_] -eq 0)
          {
           Remove-item $_
           $dirs[($_ | Split-Path -Parent)]--
           }
        }
```

...................................

Thanks @mjolinor . I like the hash table :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but I think this should work:

```
param (
[parameter (mandatory=$true,position=0)]
[string]$Path
)
$dirs = @{}

Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -Force | 
Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} |
select -ExpandProperty FullName
foreach {
         $dirs[$_] = (Get-ChildItem $_ -Force | Measure-Object).Count 
         }

$dirs.keys | Sort length -descending |
foreach {
          if ($dirs[$_] -eq 0)
            {
             Remove-Item $_
             $dirs[($_ | Split-Path -Parent)]--
             }
        }
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond to your earlier comments.  I didn't get notified that there were comments because you made them on your post, insead of mine.....

Comment: No problem. I'd rather go through some difficulty my self - this way I can make more progress than just waiting from others.

Comment: I'd rather see someone do that than just take something they don't understand and run with it :).  I think you 've got a pretty good solution there, and a good handle on how it works that you can apply to other problems.

Comment: Thanks for encouraging. I am a newbie for PS but I know I am making progress as long as I am holding on. And for sure I would like to help some others whenever possible.